# traitCollectionDidChange is not called for dark mode

Tags: swift, ios-darkmode

I'm implementing dark mode in my app, in a `viewDidLoad`. I added:

```
switch self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
case .dark:
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
case .light:
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
case .unspecified:
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
@unknown default:
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
}
```

And it works perfectly fine, but I want to set when the theme is changed on the device when the app is open, it automatically change the theme. So I added `traitCollectionDidChange` to the view controller

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
  
    switch self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle {
    case .dark:
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    case .light:
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    case .unspecified:
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    @unknown default:
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
}
```

But it's never called, should I do anything more?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to change it for yourself.
If you use **system colors**, the change will be automatic (if you don't override the default user interface style).
Delete this code, and set your colors to systemColors.

Comment: Thanks, you mean even I don't need to add anything on viewDidLoad? I already use system colors